# anchor, button not horizontally by equal padding

Tags: html, css

I have this question for very long time. Whenever I create a button in html by a tag or button tag and give css style padding top, bottom equal amount to button. But button still equally align horizontal. 
for reference find image.

[image]

for more reference find **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/by3aebby/)**

code as follows:

```
a{
    display:inline-block;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#1a8acf;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: arial, tahoma, helvetica, sans-sarif;
}
button{
    border:none;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background:#14214d;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: arial, tahoma, helvetica, sans-sarif;
}
```

Comment: umm, what? its unclear to me.

Comment: so your issue is that you can't change alignment of button? or what?

Comment: It's because you have letters that can go below the line like g and y try adding one of them (lowercase and remeasure the space)

Comment: @Pete.. Agreed with your solution.. I think line-height as per button height is only solution or padding: 12px 20px 10px; This works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `line-height` matters here, smaller fonts have a smaller default `line-height`. Set the same height for both elements and adjust the small one untill they're equal. `line-height` Also centers the font.

```
// set line height
.line-height{
    line-height: 20px;
}

// remove some button default styles (Firefox)
button::-moz-focus-inner{
  padding : 0;
  border  : 0;
}

// using block elements and floating
a{
    float: left;
    display:block;

    text-transform:uppercase;
    background:#1a8acf;
    padding:10px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: arial, tahoma, helvetica, sans-sarif;
}

button{
    display: block;
    float: left;

    border:none;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background:#14214d;
    color:#fff;
    font-family: arial, tahoma, helvetica, sans-sarif;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/by3aebby/9/)**

Comment: If my font-size is 14px. what should be the lihe-height? 
Because bootstrap gives in line-height:1.3333; 
Is there any way I kind equally put line-height as per font-size?

Comment: i've edited my answer, for better understanding and with some additions